# I want to turn off "Turn off wifi to save power" and "Turn off bluetooth to save power" features in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, bluetooth, sleep, power

Okay, so I'm using Ubuntu's latest LTS version as of 5/Dec/2018, and I have this in the gnome settings app:

Settings>Power
[image]

How do I get these features off, as turning off these buttons just turns off WiFi or Bluetooth, it won't disable the feature.

1. **How do I keep WiFi and Bluetooth on 24/7?**
2. ***Also, I would like them to remain on during sleep mode (suspend). How do I do that?***

Comment: askubuntu.com is the Ubuntu-specific forum, and you may find an answer there more rapidly.

Comment: You’re misunderstanding the menu. It’s telling you to turn off WiFi and/or Bluetooth if *you* want to save power. The gray text is just a hint. The actual label is in black. // In suspend mode, the operating system is not running. Network interfaces are pointless in this state.

Comment: The very fact that this question and all comments here exist should be a strong hint that this is just plain terrible UI design. I've never once in my life was fooled by the OS like that and that's coming from a long-time Windows user...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are not "Power saving features" but rather the toggles to disable your WiFi/Bluetooth adapters. The text is simply giving you a tip suggesting that you disable your WiFi/Bluetooth adapters to save power when you are not using them.

There is an answer on Ask Ubuntu in regards to keeping network adapters active during suspend:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022203/how-to-prevent-wifi-sleep-after-suspend

Comment: Yep, it did. Thanks a lot! It turns out I had misunderstood, and needed my question to be rephrased.

Comment: I had the same misunderstanding as OP. I thought those were power-saving features with a toggle, didn't realize they want you to manually turn BT/WIFI off there.

Comment: Agreed - the subtext is misleading

Comment: AAAH this drove me nuts.

Comment: The "helpful" explanatory text says "The WiFi can be turned off to save power."  The implication is that the toggle switch enables this characteristic.  Nope.  The WiFi and Bluetooth toggles just shut off their respective services.  This is not at all related to power management over time, so why are these toggles here?   It is not helpful to list a general fact unrelated to the function at hand. (Debian 10 Buster; gnome desktop)

Comment: yea, that message there caused me to loose access to my remote machine 300 KMs away.  I toggled it off through teamviewer only to immediately lose connection.  The subtext is misleading and potentially can have very dangerous consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I just use Caffeine shell extension from Software Center. You can also use the Caffeine app, but shell extension is better I think. They are from different dev.